# Automating a repeating pattern across multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, spreadsheet

TL;DR: I need to automate a cyclical pattern that repeats over intervals that span blocks of cells across multiple sheets.

So... I have a spreadsheet that I maintain for our work group that we use for assigning extra shifts based on who is available, and who has the lowest # of OT hours, etc.  The workbook has individual sheets for each month, and a lot of legacy formatting - originally it was used solely as the basis for a printed copy, with all the 'accounting' done by hand.  I've automated a bit of that, mainly to reduce errors carried forward from one month to the next and that sort of thing.  It's that time of year again, and I'm working on knocking out the schedule for next year.

There's a whole lot of tedious & repetitive manual work - copying to a new work book, clearing out old hours, adjusting the days of each month, marking out which dates are worked as what - 12-hr days, 12 hr nights, 8 hr days, whether they are 'half time' days (federal labor laws requiring 1.5x OT for more than 40 hrs in a given week) or holidays (being it's a 24/7/365 operations center, some workers observe the holiday on the actual day, some on their first day back, some not at all...), when the pay periods start/end, etc. etc. etc.

Oh, and just to make it more fun, there are multiple rotating shifts involved: five on a 'modified Dupont' schedule (four nights, two off, three days, one off, three nights, three off, four days, three off, four 'short' (8hr) days, seven off... rinse, lather, repeat, every 35 days.  And two others on a four on, four off schedule over an 8 wk rotation.

With different months (each month being a different sheet) having 30, 31, or 28 days, it gets 'complicated' in a hurry.  Most of the stuff mentioned above repeats in a cyclical manner, once you get used to it.  The problem is that the pattern needs to repeat over intervals that span blocks of cells across multiple sheets... and that's what I'd love to figure out how to automate next.

This is an example of what the base schedule looks like for January of next year:

[image]

Grey for holidays, blue for time-and-a-half shifts, red borders delineate pay periods, etc.  There are similar sheets for each month, with the patterns extending from one to the next.

Here is a reference example of the various sequences in their 'raw' form:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code or conditional formatting you have done for this and explain whee the problem with it is. Have you considered Excel may not be the best tool for this?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad no code as of yet, as I have haven't been able to find anything to even remotely suggest a starting point.  At best, I've been considering generating the whole thing from scratch using python and openxl, but that's pretty much a scorched-earth option.   Not the end of the world, but I was hoping to stay witin Excel itself if possible.  If it comes down to using VBA or Python, I'm much more inclined to use the latter.

Comment: And yes, I would agree that this is absolutely a case of bashing a square peg through a round hole, and abusing Excel in ways that it was never meant for.  There absolutely are commercial programs that do all manner of intricate scheduling like this, and more.  Internal politics (between IT and the rest of the company) make that a no-go.  So I'm left trying to make a once-a-year task slightly less painful, for my own benefit, no one else's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is actually pretty well suited for this - custom rules and numerous schedules, manual adjustments. You'll be hard pressed to find anything better bar a custom program. There is a lot that could be done to improve the template:

1. Use Excel's built-in date functions. Something like WORKDAY has built-in support for holidays. Flag holidays with conditional formatting.
2. Create a setup sheet that creates the starting conditions (year, holidays saved as a named range etc.). Link the January sheet to this one with a start date, then daisy chain the others.
3. Create schedules as named range arrays e.g. *mdupont* defined as `={"N","N","N","N","","","","D","D","D","","N","N","N","","","","D","D","D","D","","","","8","8","8","8","","","","","","",""}`

To get to a schedule value, use `=INDEX(mdupont, MOD((day-1+sshift),35)+1)` where *day* is the day # in the year and *sshift* is a relative shift between different schedules. *day* could be determined e.g. as `=(A1&" February "&startyear) - ("1 January"&" "&startyear) +1` where startyear is a named range in the setup sheet.

If you need to do manual changes in the schedule (compensate for holidays, or accommodate personal schedules) then maybe make hidden rows above each schedule row. The hidden row contains the schedule index number and increments by 1 (with mod 35) most of the time, but would allow you to manually intervene and change a schedule out-of-order. In this case you would need to have schedule start and stop index values that daisy chain from one month sheet to the next.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions; I will give them a shot next time I'm back on shift.

The schedule as I set it up is usually the starting point for everyone else (there's about a half-dozen other fingers in this particular pie) to mark it up for call-outs, hold-overs, vacation coverage, etc. etc.  

I will look at using the hidden rows as you suggest; alternately I was thinking of using the formulae to generate the patterns in the sheets, then converting to values - or otherwise protecting things - so the end users can't 'touch' the important bits.  Learned that lesson the hard way.

Comment: I've got most of the rest of the sheet hammered into a little better shape, with more automation going on as far as the days of the month, weekdays, holidays and pay periods... still trying to get the repeating patterns to work from one sheet to the next.

I've got named ranges set up for offsets for the various shifts, and have this for a formula at this point:

=IF(INDEX(mdupont,MOD((DAY(C$3)-1+offset_A),35)+1)=0,"",INDEX(mdupont,MOD((DAY(C$3)-1+offset_A),35)+1))

By tweaking the offsets I can get everything to line up for January... but not February.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Ah you are using the DAY formula which returns 1..31, not 1..365, which means that each month you start off a fresh at the 1st position of the schedule and there is no continuity month to month. To get the absolute day number of the year 1..365, you have to subtract the first day of the year from the current date (in Excel, if you subtract two dates from each other the return result with be the difference in days), for 0..364 and plus 1 for 1..365.

Comment: Ps. Kindly checkmark the solution if it worked for you.

Comment: So does 'day' need to be recalculated dynamically for each and every day of the calendar?  You presented it as two separate formulae, but it seems like the one would need to be nested inside the other, which gets ugly - and easy to mess up - in a hurry.

Comment: I've already got 'C1' filled with '=date(start_year,1,1)'  (for January), with subsequent days as '=C1+1', '=D1+1', etc. , and then custom formatted using 'd' to give the same visual appearance of 1-31.  As I understand it, that should mean that 'C1' and the rest of those cells should already contain the serial value for the date...?

Comment: Success!  (I think)

After a lot of tinkering, this is what I have for a cell formula, which seems to work consistently (at least for the first three months):

=IF(INDEX(mdupont,(MOD((C$1-DATE(start_year,1,1)+1)-1+offset_A,35)+1))=0,"",INDEX(mdupont,(MOD((C$1-DATE(start_year,1,1)+1)-1+offset_A,35)+1)))

Comment: Glad it worked. Question, why do you have the `IF INDEX(mdupoint,...) = 0 then ""` bit? You define mdupoint, and there is no 0 in it? And if you did put a 0 in the defined name, just replace it with "" already in the definition. The only problem I see is that you might be trying to compensation for an error. If mdupoint has 35 entries, your index number must be 1..35. Index 0  or 36+ would return unintended results. However, since we use MOD(..., 35)+1, we will always get an index between 1..35.

Comment: I used the =if(isblank(index(mdupoint,...),"",index(mdupoint,...) bit because mdupoint references a row of cells with "N", "D" or blank/empty as appropriate for the sequence.  Indexing to a 'blank' cell returns a '0' value in this cell, which is not the look I'm going for.

Comment: Correction, I was thinking of the =if(isblank(),"",...) that I used elsewhere on the sheet for similar reasons.  But the point remains: if I don't test for a "0" result and block it, that's what I get in the cell.